# Setting JAVA_HOME in .bash_profile not returning correct path

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm on a MacOS Catalina 10.15.1. I've got multiple versions of Java and I want to set the `JAVA_HOME` path to one of them but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I've got:

```sh
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    13, x86_64: "OpenJDK 13"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_275, x86_64:  "AdoptOpenJDK 8"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_241, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home
```

`~/.bash_profile`:

```sh
# tried these:
#export JAVA_HOME_8=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
#export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME_8
# weren't working so tried this instead:
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ java -version
```

```
openjdk version "13" 2019-09-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13+33)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Was expecting `java -version` to return version 8 but looks like I'm getting version 13? Not sure why. One of those :/ moments...any ideas?

Comment: If you want to manage your Java version easily, I can recommend [JEnv](https://www.jenv.be/). With it, the exchange of the version works very well.

Comment: I am so dumb! I checked `.bash_profile` again and scrolled down to see this: `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` ... ffs....

Answer (score 3):

You aren't adjusting your `PATH` with the `JAVA_HOME` you're setting. Try adding `export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"`

I also highly recommend using [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) to manage your Java language(s). It even has spark support, `sdk ls spark`

```
$ sdk ls spark
==== BROADCAST =================================================================
* 2020-12-26: java 16.ea.30-open available on SDKMAN!
* 2020-12-26: java 17.ea.3-open available on SDKMAN!
* 2020-12-23: micronaut 2.2.2 available on SDKMAN!
================================================================================
================================================================================
Available Spark Versions
================================================================================
     3.0.1               2.2.0
     3.0.0               2.1.3
     2.4.7               2.1.2
     2.4.6               2.1.1
     2.4.5               2.0.2
     2.4.4               1.6.3
     2.4.3               1.5.2
     2.4.2               1.4.1
     2.4.1
     2.4.0
     2.3.3
     2.3.2
     2.3.1
     2.3.0
     2.2.1

================================================================================
+ - local version
* - installed
> - currently in use
================================================================================
```